# Register Instance in ASPNET Core DI

Tags: asp.net-core

I am converting some code from Unity to use ASPNET Core's built in DI, I came across the following scenario that I need to register (an instance of). How can I go about doing it?

```
    var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperBootstrapper.ServicesProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperBootstrapper.WebApiProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperBootstrapper.WebProfile>();
    });

    // register mapper config
    var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
```

In Unity I did:

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(mapper);
```

But I am not sure how to do it in core.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the factory pattern of IServiceCollection.

```
services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => {
    var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperBootstrapper.ServicesProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperBootstrapper.WebApiProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperBootstrapper.WebProfile>();
    });
    return mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
});
```

Or just

`services.AddSingleton(mapper);`

Comment: What about `RegisterType`?

Comment: Can you explain ?